# Get list timeline by using Twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

I want to get list timeline by using Twitter gem.

How can I call GET lists/statuses REST API from Twitter gem?
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/lists/statuses

I've searched through documentation but couldn't found proper method.
http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter

**Problem solved**
I overlooked the method `list_timeline`. It serves as lists/statuses.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'twitter' gem.

Create an app on [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/). You need to give to it read & write access just for sake of your own experiments.

Use this sample code (with your credentials you've got from Twitter). Please note that I'm using some public list URI (list = URI.parse('https://twitter.com/sferik/presidents')
p client.list_timeline(list))

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end

list = URI.parse('https://twitter.com/sferik/presidents')
client.list_timeline(list)
```

for more info please visit [Twitter gem docs.](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter#Usage_Examples)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading the gem documentation. You'll also have to register your application with twitter to get your oauth parameters.

https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Answer (score 0):

To get the timeline from a list using [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) :

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end

# For each list of the user
client.lists.each do |list|
  # Get the timeline with the list ID
  client.list_timeline(list.id).each do |tweet|
    puts tweet.text
  end
end
```