# rails twitter gem list retrieve/display full tweet

Tags: list, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, rubygems

I am displaying the tweets from a [public list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741173/get-list-timeline-by-using-twitter-gem) but when a tweet has an image it is not displaying the image nor the link of the image but `...`  and sometimes even the text of the tweet is truncated with `...`.
How can I make the full tweet text display even if the image is not?
I need the full text for each tweet in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing an API call :

$client.get(“https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?owner_screen_name=USERNAME&slug=LISTNAME&tweet_mode=extended”)